# Was YHWH targeting Egyptian gods or that's just Jack Chick's idiocy?

Tags: exodus

[image]
[image]

According to this tract of Jack Chick, the 10 Plagues were targeting/disgracing major Egyptian gods.

The most glaring issue with this is:

WHERE IS MAH BOI, SOBEK?!

**On a serious note, I'm unsure if this explanation is actually a thing outside of this tract. Is it?**

Comment: When I was teaching Sunday school years ago, I investigated the Egyptian pantheon to see if each plague corresponded to one of their Gods. It does. However, the Egyptians worshiped hundreds of gods. Mercifully, God did not strike them with one plague for each of their gods, or they would all have died.

Comment: You know, if you have a god for everything, what kind of plague could possibly not, in hindsight, be interpreted as targeting one of the gods? I don't want to say it's wrong, but a little dubious reasoning.

Comment: @kutschkem - I understand your statement - however, the gods that each plague mocked were the main gods.

Comment: @Dottard 1. I guess that equals a crying Seth. 2. Does that imply lesser deities were a thing here?

Comment: @Mephistopheles - I do not understand this cryptic comment.

Comment: @Dottard 1. I think Set was a rather prominent deity for Egyptians, so him getting excluded from the Plagues means YHWH was extra mean to him. 2. Since the mages could replicate YHWH's tricks to a degree, and that YHWH "JUDGED" the Egyptian gods, points towards that for me. And by that, I mean that there were other powers besides YHWH, but they were weak.